# Deleted unreferenced records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

Suppose I have table A and B. Table A has a FK to Table B.

I could categorize records in B as 'referenced' and 'unreferenced', meaning that there's some record in the database that has a FK pointing to that record or not, respectively.

I want to find a *scheme-independent* way to delete all rows in B which are unreferenced.
Doing a simple DELETE of table B without any constraints (because I want to be *scheme-independent*, i.e. a general way), almost certainly, it will fail.

If it could also be vendor independent would be great, but I feel I'm asking for too much.

Edit: Maybe I wasn't clear. When I say I don't want to depend on the scheme, I refer avoiding naming column names from other tables when doing the 'DELETE'. Just deleting records of B which can be deleted without breaking DB consistency.

Comment: what do you mean by `I do not want to depend on the scheme. I want a general way.`?

Comment: "*I refer avoiding naming column names from other tables*" - that's not possible. You **have** to have some kind of "relation" between the tables and they are done by comparing columns.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this could not be done. Maybe it couldn't be done in a SQL statement... I'd accept that, but that's not a constraint.

Comment: @peterRit why do this way?

Comment: DB maintenance. Suppose you want to do this job for a hundred tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow way:

```
declare del_cur cursor
local
forward_only
static
scroll_locks
for
  select 0 from B
;

declare @foo int;

open del_cur;

fetch next from del_cur into @foo;
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  begin try
    delete from B where current of del_cur;
  end try
  begin catch
    -- It was referenced, skip
  end catch;

  fetch next from del_cur into @foo;
end;

close del_cur;
deallocate del_cur;
```

A faster way would be examining the existing foreign keys and building a dynamic SQL statement that includes their column names.

Comment: Good, slow way but works!. I'd would be interested in the dynamic SQL statement. Could you expand a bit about that solution or provide some reference?

Comment: @peterRit Query a [list of foreign keys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) that exist for a given `OBJECT_ID(table_name)`, that gives you column names. Having a list of column names, build a dynamic `delete from B where colname1 is null and colname2 is null and colname3 is null`.